# Connect app with O365 app launcher is not working

Tags: c#, .net, azure, single-sign-on, office365-apps

I found .NET application https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-multitenant-openidconnect which asks user to loin. After login, I am able to see the app in user myapps. If i revoke permissions to in users myapps dashboard, then from next login onwards consent page is not showing and applicaion is not appears in user myapps. Kindly help me in understanding what is happening here?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but I think the key here is "If I revoke permissions".....what permissions are you revoking?

Comment: @Tim https://www.dropbox.com/s/tzkjk81nxmqjaya/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: When consent screen comes? Only for the first time login of the user?

Comment: Found solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30767270/azure-active-directory-login-web-app-permissions-user-consent-not-triggered