# Azure Authentication Middleware for a Laravel App

Tags: php, laravel, azure-active-directory

First of all, i am very new to Laravel and Azure and i am not very sure what i am doing.

I want to add Authentication to my Laravel Web Application.

I followed the instructions in [this Link](https://github.com/rootinc/laravel-azure-middleware) to do that:

When i press my Login Button, which leeds me to "/login/azure" i get directed to

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/ef7e48cb-7676-47e9-9a28-c69910d92560/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=3a0621c0-2848-47f5-83ee-bebeede8aaa6&resource=`

I can add my credentials here and then i get redirected to my welcome page and there is a very long code in my uri and after that a short session code. What does this mean? Am i logged in now? How can i test that and how can i create different roles for my Application now?

Could it be that i have to enable the default laravel Authentication with the "php artisan make:auth" command? Is it bad that i have no resource in the uri u see above? What do i have to put there?

Comment: to see if your logged in you can add in your blade this `@if(auth()->check())<h1>Hello World</h1>@endif` to create different roles in the application you need to start using the middleware of laravel [tutorial laravel middleware](http://connorleech.info/blog/Build-a-quick-admin-panel-in-Laravel-5/) it shows you how to make an admin role what you can also make more roles like that like mod etc

Answer (score 0):

First, understand OAuth on Azure.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code

You do not need a resource if you are using the "converged" endpoint (v2).  The endpoint you show is v1, so yes, you need to specify what `resource` you're authenticating against and what `grant`ed permissions are for it.  Check out [What is the Resource parameter in Windows Azure AD tenant application oAuth 2.0 specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921884/what-is-the-resource-parameter-in-windows-azure-ad-tenant-application-oauth-2-0)

Have you created an app registration (see the Azure Active Directory blade)?

Welcome to OAuth.

Comment: Thanks for the first Link. I already found that and was wondering if i need to understand that. Now i will go through it.

What do you mean with Azure Active Directory Blade? Is that the B2C Blade? I don't have permission to do something with the B2C stuff because my Company doesn't want me to do something with that. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: the vertical tabs - called blades

Comment: ah yeah, there is an app registration for my page